# Change colour for short period of time JavaScript & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing simple ID validating html page with javascript. My idea is, whenever user enters a valid ID number, the text field of form changes its colour for few seconds and then revert back to normal.

the code

```
<script>
var abcArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var IDweights = [7,3,1,0,7,3,1,7,3];
var valuesMap = new Map();
for(var i=0;i<26;i++){
    valuesMap.set(abcArray[i],i+10);
}
validateID();

function validateID(){
    var idNumber = document.forms.form.idnum.value.toUpperCase();
    var sumOfValues = 0;

    for(var x = 0; x < idNumber.length; x++){
        if(x < 3){
            sumOfValues += (valuesMap.get(idNumber.charAt(x))*IDweights[x]);
        } 
        if(x > 3){  
            sumOfValues += (parseInt(idNumber.charAt(x))*IDweights[x]);
        }
    }
    if(sumOfValues % 10 == idNumber[3]){
        var y = document.getElementById("idnum");
        y.style.animation = "anim 5s";   // when true change to green 
    } else {
        var y = document.getElementById("idnum");
        y.style.animation = "anim1 5s"; //change to red
    }
}
```

the css part

```
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
0% {background:white;}
20% {background:green;}
100% {background:white;}
}
@-moz-keyframes anim {
0% {background:white;}
20% {background:green;}
100% {background:white;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim1 {
0% {background:white;}
20% {background:red;}
100% {background:white;}
}
@-moz-keyframes anim1 {
0% {background:white;}
20% {background:red;}
100% {background:white;}
}
```

It works but only once. When I click validate button again, then nothing happens. Only when I change ID number for the wrong one, then it works but only once as well, and then again to make it work you need to put the correct one... I am aware it's probably because I'm setting css properties once and thats it, the browser will not change them again if they're the same. But I can't think of proper solution because I'm new to JS and css. I searched for quite long and still didn't find any solution for my problem, partly because I don't really know how to specify it. I'll be grateful for your help.

PS. please only pure js and css - I'am not familiar with jquery yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is, if the element already has the style="anim1 5s" for example - setting it to that same value again will do nothing. You would need to remove that style, and then add it again.

Better still, when you add the style, add an [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event listener to that element to remove that animation when the animation completes

```
function validateID() {
    var doneAnimating = function(e) {
        // remove the listener
        this.removeEventListener('animationend', doneAnimating);
        // remove the animate style
        this.style.animate = '';
    }
    var idNumber = document.forms.form.idnum.value.toUpperCase();
    var sumOfValues = 0;

    for (var x = 0; x < idNumber.length; x++) {
        if (x < 3) {
            sumOfValues += (valuesMap.get(idNumber.charAt(x)) * IDweights[x]);
        }
        if (x > 3) {
            sumOfValues += (parseInt(idNumber.charAt(x)) * IDweights[x]);
        }
    }
    // moved outside of if/then to tidy up code
    var y = document.getElementById("idnum");
    // add the listener to the element
    y.addEventListener('animationend', doneAnimating);
    if (sumOfValues % 10 == idNumber[3]) {
        y.style.animation = "anim 5s"; // when true change to green 
    } else {
        y.style.animation = "anim1 5s"; //change to red
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply (outside of this code) add the `animationend` event listener once, and the `doneAnimating` can simply remove the animate style and not worry about removing the event listener - in fact you can put the event handler inline to make it very simple

```
// this is done once only - not sure where in your code you'd put it
document.getElementById("idnum").addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
    this.style.animate = '';
});

function validateID() {
    var idNumber = document.forms.form.idnum.value.toUpperCase();
    var sumOfValues = 0;

    for (var x = 0; x < idNumber.length; x++) {
        if (x < 3) {
            sumOfValues += (valuesMap.get(idNumber.charAt(x)) * IDweights[x]);
        }
        if (x > 3) {
            sumOfValues += (parseInt(idNumber.charAt(x)) * IDweights[x]);
        }
    }
    // moved outside of if/then to tidy up code
    var y = document.getElementById("idnum");
    if (sumOfValues % 10 == idNumber[3]) {
        y.style.animation = "anim 5s"; // when true change to green 
    } else {
        y.style.animation = "anim1 5s"; //change to red
    }
}
```